# React native 'Network error' with post Custom header and form data

Tags: react-native, axios

I am trying to upload some data using axios post request and custom headers. Here is my code.

```
 axios
  .post('https://website.domain/api/ads/create', new FormData(), {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer 123',
    },
  })
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({ message: JSON.stringify(res) });
  })
  .catch(res => {
    this.setState({ message: JSON.stringify(res.response) });
  });
```

this works fine with `Expo` ([here](https://snack.expo.io/@bungler/vengeful-banana) is the source)

But when move to react native it does not work. It gives me the error:

```
{message:"Network error".....}
```

PS: other methods like post without authorization, get all are working except this one.[image]

Comment: What is the data structure of `new FormData()` ?

Comment: Dont you know what is form data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! The trick was with uploading the file: with expo you need to remove `//file` prefix of file path while in `react-native` it should be preserved!